# Could not install any python packages in python virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask-restful

I'm trying to deploy my flask app in apach 2 server which is running on ubuntu 16.04. For that i created a python virtual env using the following commands:-

apt-get install -y python3-pip
apt-get install -y python3-venv
python3 -m venv yourenvironment
source yourenvironment/bin/activate

after activating the virtual environment , I tried install flask in my virtual environment using the command

pip3 install Flask

**error msg:**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/yourenvironment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MarkupSafe-1.0.dist-info'

I tried sudo pip3 install Flask, then got msg requirement already satisfied.

but when try to run a simple flask app, i'm getting import error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**init**.py", line 1, in 
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'

Please anyone help me. I'm really stuck in this issue

Comment: What directory is your project located in? Are you trying to create it in `var/www`?

Comment: I followed this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: Can you try checking the permissions for files in your app directory? `chmod 775 /var/www/FlaskApp -R`. You may also need to give permissions to the group: `chmod -R g+w /var/www/FlaskApp`

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the issue may be that there's a permission issue where your superuser can install and access dependencies, but the app itself does not have those abilities.